# How can I run a extension with Google Chrome for Youtube?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

**Hello there,
I want to remove thumbnail images that appear on YouTube. I am using the following code for this.**

```
while (true) {
    $("ytd-thumbnail").remove()
}
```

**When I paste this code into console, all thumbnail images are removed. I want it to work on the backplane by adding an extension. The code for the plug-in I'm preparing is below.**

> manifest.json;

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "test",
    "description": "test extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

> popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <button id="checkPage">Check !</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

> popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');

    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            d = document;

            while (true) {
                $("ytd-thumbnail").remove()
            }
        });
    }, false);
}, false);
```

**When I press the checkPage button nothing happens. But this code works when I add a console. What is the problem? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Do some debugging on your own. `console.log($)`. `console.log($('ytd-thumbnail'))`. Does it contain jquery? Does it contain the elements you're looking for?

Comment: Does not have jQuery. I'm learning new .js and I do not understand. I try to learn by trying and asking. @FrankerZ

Comment: I would look into basic debugging first, before asking more questions. `console.log()` and the debugger are your friends. If something isn't expected, add breakpoints, log out where you think problems are. Does it contain what you're expecting? No? Then figure out why. Google "Why is $ not working in my chrome extension".

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the extension :

1. You are trying to use $ i.e. jquery which is not available in your
   popup.js
2. You are trying to access "ytd-thumbnail" dom elements which belong
   to youtube page and not your popup.html. So, even if you replace $
   with document.querySelector , you won't find those elements.

I created a working version that looks something like this. I have not included popup.html which is same as yours.

> 1. manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,  
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "description" : "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {    
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],     
    "js": ["background.js"],
    "all_frames" : true

  }
 ],
 "permissions": [
    "activeTab",  
    "tabs"
 ]
}
```

> 2.popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
{
   var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
   checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() 
    {

        chrome.tabs.query({"active":true}, function (tabs){             

           chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "removeThumbnails", function (response) {
                    });             
            });
    });         
});
```

When the button is clicked, retrieve the active tab and send it a "removeThumbnails" message.

> 3.background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, callback) {

    if (message == "removeThumbnails")
    {       
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("ytd-thumbnail");
        elements.forEach(a => a.parentNode.removeChild(a));
    }
});
```

background.js is content script and runs in  youtube page. It can now access all the dom elements in youtube page. When we receive a "removeThumbnails" message , get all ytd-thumbnail elements and remove them from page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable reply. This certainly works and I learned how. I would like to ask you 2 questions based on your knowledge.
Question 1: How can I run this code (background.js) continuously on the backplane? The images are hidden when we click but the images are displayed again when we load the page again or when we load more. We need to press the button again. @Nish26

Comment: Question 2: Is it possible to remove videos like this? I added this code to my background.js file. Buttons are used to remove the video but we are removing the whole YouTube page because I use the wrong name.

var elements = document.querySelectorAll ("ytd-watch-flexy");
        elements.forEach (a => a.parentNode.removeChild (a));

Do not worry. When we hit Buttons, I guess we can reduce the video height with a .js code. For example; height: 240 px; to height: 0 px; we will make the size of the video will not appear 0 px but the voice will come. @Nish26

Comment: For 1, you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) api . You should consider modifying your manifest to run your content scripts only on youtube.com if you do this.  For 2, I am not sure if i understood your question properly. From what i could understand, maybe you can just use css visibility to control whether the video elements are visible or not.